# UICollectionViewCell: Are there any events fired when cell visibility changes?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Our app plays videos in a collection view cells.  Apparently, there is a limit on the number of AVPlayers on a screen (16 I believe) so we need to initialize an AVPlayer and AVPlayerController when a collection view cell becomes visible and release them when the cell becomes invisible.

Are there any events fired when cell visibility changes? Is there a better approach to the above solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sure, `UICollectionViewDelegate` has methods: `collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:)` and `collectionView(_:didEndDisplaying:forItemAt:)`. Also you can use `visibleCells` property of `UICollectionView` to check number of visible cells.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for these two methods

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                 willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, 
                   forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)

optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
            didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, 
                   forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Check them in appledoc. [WillDisplayCell](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618087-collectionview) & [EndDisplayingCell](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618006-collectionview)